# Just aHow to override application.properties in Spring when using Java Configuration's AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, configuration

Is there a way to override your application.properties file when using Java configuration.  E.g. in my code I start Spring by using an AppConfig class to handily configure some stuff:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
context.register(AppConfig.class);
context.refresh();
Application application = context.getBean(Application.class);
application.start();
```

Within my AppConfig class I have something like this where I'm using the application.properties file to initialize beans:

```
@Autowired
Environment env;

@Bean
public ApplicationManager applicationManager(){
    nodeName = env.getProperty("node.name");
    ApplicationManager applicationManager =  new ApplicationManager();
    applicationManager.setNodeName(nodeName);
    return  applicationManager;
}
```

The Environment env is based on the application.properties file. However, even if I start the application from the command line like this:

*java -jar myJar --spring.config.location=[new application.properties location]*

the same baked in application.properties file is used for the basis of the Environment, and not the one I am attempting to use from the command line.

It seems the spring.config.location isn't overridden when using the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext -I did experiment and did notice that if I use:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
Application application = context.getBean(Application.class);
application.start();
```

then the application.properties is overridden as you would think, but obviously then you lose the java configuration using the AppConfig.class.  Is there a way to have your cake and eat it?  Any thoughts are welcome and thanks!

To be clear here is my Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public Application(){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfig.class);
        context.refresh();
        Application application = context.getBean(Application.class);
        application.start();
    }

    public void start() {
      ...start stuff here....
    }
}
```

Just an update for anyone who might be in a similar position:

The whole reason that this wasn't working for me was the fact I was passing in the Application.class (not a configuration class as m deinum pointed out!) and using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext to get the context -this is easily rectified by passing in the AppConfig.class (a configuration class) I'd created and using the SpringApplication helper class to obtain the ConfigurableApplicationContext.  Then, based on whether or not you pass in an external reference to an application.properties file at the command line it will work :)  Here is a code snippet that works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    SomeClass someClass = context.getBean("SomeClass.class");
    someClass.doThis();  //start your app doing something here
}
```

Comment: NO you won't loose your `AppConfig` class, make sure it gets scanned. The `Application` class, when used with Spring Boot should actually be a configuration class. Also if it doesn't work you are doing weird things in your setup (and judging from what you are trying to do you are actually doing that).

Comment: thanks for the response.....  Maybe I have this screwed up, for the application class I have:

Comment: Don't add code/xml etc. as comments. Instead edit your question.

Comment: thanks M. Deinum, and again, thanks for the feedback.  TBH, I didn't think I was doing weird stuff -I was attempting to use the java configuration and then simply pass in a config file it could use?  I liked the java configuration as it makes it easier to manipulate the properties.  I think what you said is that I should be using  class other than Application to be annotated with SpringBootApplication, and make sure Application is annotated with Component/Configurable as well as make sure the AppConfig is scanned...  I'll give it a go.

Comment: The `@SpringBootApplication` will be autowired etc. just like a regular class. Looks like you are misunderstanding things, I suggest a read on Spring and Spring Boot and how those things works.

Comment: OK will do and thanks, clearly I'm missing something here.

Comment: added an update, everything works as expected now

Comment: The fact that you use a separate configuration class and not the application class itself as well the fact that you need some helper class to access the context still sounds like you are doing things you shouldn't be doing. Generally when you need access to the `ApplicationContext` you are doing things wrong (unless writing framework code) is a good rule of thumb,

Comment: I do like the idea of having a separate class that takes care of all the configuration.  Looking at the Spring tutorials online, it seems most do use a context to get a bean to start the application as a whole.... can you provide a link/simple example of how you would do it? Again, thanks for your responses.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot not plain Spring. Also why would you need to start your application? The `@SpringBootAPplication` annotated class should be the start of your application. Looks like you are trying to work around the framework.